# ITimeouts does not contain a definition for ImplicitWait in Appium

Tags: appium, appium-desktop

I am trying to get this Calculator sample working from https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/tree/master/Samples/C%23/CalculatorTest but I couldn't get the "ImplicitWait" resolved. VS suggested to use `ImplicitlyWait` but still not working. I have an appium.webdriver v3.0.0.2 and the sample still using the preview version.

Full error message:

`ITimeouts does not contain a definition for 'ImplicitWait' and no accessible extension method 'ImplicitWait' accepting a first argument of type 'ITimeouts' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Code:

```
public static void Launch(TestContext context)
{
   var appCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
   appCapabilities.SetCapability("app", AppId);
   appCapabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
   appCapabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "Windows");
   session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(DriverUrl), appCapabilities);
   Assert.IsNotNull(session);
   session.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5);
}
```

Comment: did you try `session.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));`? it is obsolete as of wd 3.1 but maybe it works in your current version

Comment: Thanks @Marc Sances that works on my version. What is the implementation for wd 3.1?

Comment: The one you were trying to do in your code snippet.